# Centralise database using wifi or lan , using frontend as java(swing) n backend as oracle 10g

Tags: java, swing, oracle10g, wifi

I have developed Desktop application in java (Swing)
and i have used oracle 10g database
 So how to use the software in wifi means In lappy # 1 content database and lappy # 2 content only jar file and jdk , when lappy #2 save some data then this data should be save on lappy # 1 database ...
      guys please help me about this..
  Thank's in advance..

Comment: You need some kind of service element that can take data in, store it the database and notify all other parties that the data has changed - assuming I'm reading the question right

Comment: Also consider [_replication_](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14226/toc.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have described 1 laptop (lappy?) with a desktop application (in Java) and a local database (db1). You have a 2nd laptop with a local database (db2). You wish to reflect changes made to db1, in db2.

If db2 is a read-only database, then replication is a simple solution and would be configured at the database layer. If db2 can also be written to, then you may need to consider circular replication, if you need to reflect those changes in db1.

Since your set up is networked, you could have a single database server and have the laptops use that. This would remove the need for synchronisation. If you need to have the data available offline, then this won't be an option.

In this instance, I don't think it's relevant that the client is a Java application and that your network is wireless.